# What should be "аккуратно подхрюкивать"?

Tags: значения

Путин: "США сами все нарушают, а их сателлиты *аккуратно* им *подхрюкивают*".

What should that exactly mean? Are NATO leaders compared here pejoratively to disciplined swines due to their agreements with US those (the agreements/acceptance) he wants to criticize as unlawful?

Comment: yes, this is a derogatory way typical of putin when speaking of the West (or anything he doesn't like) to say that the allies 'sing along with the US', commonly used synonyms of **подхрюкивать** are **подгавкивать, подтявкивать** (which refer to dogs)

Answer (score 3):

In this case аккуратно means carefully. 
And подхрюкивать means that NATO leaders is yes-men

So here oink-oink of swines compared to yes-yes(agreements of Nato leaders with US)